# How do you get Zekrom and Reshiram in ORAS?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

How and where can I catch Zekrom and Reshiram in Pokemon Alpha Sapphire and Omega Ruby?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

guys and girls of course you also need to bring a pokemon of Max level, which is a level 100 pokemon. It does not matter what type of pokemon though.

Answer (score 6):

When Soaring around, you may discover a small area near Mauville City which has a star above it. This is the Fabled Cave and inside the cave you will find another portal. In it, you will encounter Reshiram in Omega Ruby or Zekrom in Alpha Sapphire.

Source : http://www.serebii.net/omegarubyalphasapphire/legendary.shtml

The source also contains the locations of all the other legendaries.

[image: The protal in the Fabled Cave]

Answer (score 1):

Near Mauville City, if you fly with Latias/Latios, there should be a location called "Fabled Cave". Inside, you'll find a portal. If you interact with it, you will encounter Zekrom/Reshiram, depending on your version.